# Add Google Analytics JS event tracker

Tags: javascript, analytics

I'm trying to track some link clicks on a website that is using Craft CMS.
I only have access to the Website and the Data Studio Report, but I don't have access to Google Analytics, GTM or any "deeper" level of the Control Panel. Thus, I thought I'd try to send the events directly to Analytics.
Google has [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) How-To on their site, for which I need to implement the following script (beside an `onclick` event which is no problem):

```
<script>
/**
* Function that captures a click on an outbound link in Analytics.
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
* as the event label. Setting the transport method to 'beacon' lets the hit be sent
* using 'navigator.sendBeacon' in browser that support it.
*/
var captureOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>
```

Unfortunately I got basically no idea about JavaScript or Twig and every time I try to include the code, it simply gets deleted. I guess it's because I need to transform the script into Twig - but I got no idea how to do this. My colleagues can't help me either, as they have even less of a programming understand than I do.

Can anyone help me out how to add this script?

Answer (score 1):

You can add JS code to your twig template via [JS tag](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/twig-primer.html#tags), for example

> templates/basic-layout.twig:

```
{% js %}
     ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
{% endjs %}
```

Or you can use [{% block %} tag](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/block.html), e.g. somewhere in the footer

```
    {% block footerJs %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

And call it in the necessary template:

> templates/example-section/entry.twig:

```
{% extends "basic_layout.twig" %}
{# ... some your code here ..#}
    {% block footerJs %}
             ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
             'transport': 'beacon',
             'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
           });
    {% endblock %}
```